# django return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table:

Tags: django, database

I have a simple model class as below

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    code= models.CharField(max_length=5)
    status=models.BooleanField()
    create_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and I want to use it like this

```
llist = Language.objects.filter()
list1 = []
for rs in llist:
    list1.append((rs.code,rs.name))
langlist = (list1)
```

but it keeps throwing this error when I try to use `llist` :

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: home_language
```

I tried to use `python manage.py shell` to make queries and it's showing the same above error.

This is the full error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: home_language

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "c:\users\daisy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\OneDrive\Documents\Work\django\prjs\funnystore\mysite\home\models.py", line 29, in <module>
    for rs in llist:
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 276, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1152, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Daisy\Downloads\Django-E-Commerce-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: home_language
```

Comment: For a new app that doesn't yet have any migrations you need to pass the app name to `makemigrations` to create the initial migration file: `python manage.py makemigrations home`. Then run `python manage.py migrate `

Comment: try changing class name to `language` and then use `llist = language.objects.filter()` also don't forget to `makemigrations` and `migrate` again

Comment: I tried the above suggestions but this error happens before migration so it doesn't work

Comment: @Knight "this error happens before migration": do you mean you get the error when trying to create migrations? If so, you need to move this code so it is not executed on start-up of your app

Comment: @IainShelvington this error also happens whenever I try any command with manage.py

Comment: @chaitanya there is nothing wrong with `llist = Language.objects.filter()` but it has issue when I try to use llist after that

Comment: You're executing a query somewhere in your app on start-up. Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @Knight I had  encountered the same issue. I had class named `Images` and the table created was `home_Images` as my app name was `home` and I used `Images.objects.all()` so django searched for table named `home_images` and it didn't find table `home_images`, my error was exactly same as yours. when I tried changing class name to `images` everything worked fine.

Comment: @chaitanya it doesn't work in my case :P

Comment: @Knight this code is in your models.py file executing a query when the file is loaded, migrations will load the file which is causing the error. Remove the code from your models.py and you should be able to migrate. Why is it in the root of that file in the first place though?

Comment: @IainShelvington I can't remove because I'm using `langlist` for other classes. It will be like this :
`class SettingLang(models.Model):
     lang =  models.CharFi(max_length=6, choices=langlist)`

Comment: @Knight Without seeing where you are using `langlist` it's hard to give advice, can't whatever you are doing be replaced by a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: Thanks @IainShelvington , ForeignKey works with this case

Comment: @IainShelvington I found the root cause, it is because I'm getting the database at the same time with creating it, so there is no data to get when execute, I need to add some values before adding query code, and it works perfectly. But it's so clumsy and impractical, Is there any way to make an exception for querying with no table value ?

Comment: "this code is in your models.py file executing a query when the file is loaded, migrations will load the file which is causing the error. Remove the code from your models.py and you should be able to migrate. " @IainShelvington This comment helped me immensely after a few hours of frustration. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use this code on your command prompt:

python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb

this worked for me........

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I used the migration for the specific app, in your case it's:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations home
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make migrations and migrate the database using:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Error was solved with removing data through your admin panel in advance.
Then:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete this model (home_language) from all of your codes if you used it in any condition, and then migrate it:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

i hope it should work.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete the SQLite db and files in the migration folder and then run the command

```
python manage.py makemigrations <your name app>
```

and then python manage.py migrate.

```
python manage.py makemigrations (your app name)
python manage.py migrate
```